# Configure sidekiq to work without brocker in development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, celery, sidekiq

It would've been a nice feature to configure `sidekiq` to work synchronously on development environment - without installing and starting redis, no retrying and so on *though I'm not saying that it is so hard to be done*

> For example [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) has this feature as `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER=True` in settings

Does sidekiq have a support for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, sidekiq supports this. From the [sidekiq wiki](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing):

```
require 'sidekiq/testing'
Sidekiq::Testing.inline!
```

That would run the jobs synchronously. If you want them to not run instead, you can use `Sidekiq::Testing.fake!`

Answer (score 1):

The sidekiq developer says that he [doesn't want to provide](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/3384) this feature.

Current sidekiq implementation puts a warning if you run it using the Testing.inline! mode outside test environment.